# I can't seem to get his c++ script to not return a 0 at one point

Tags: c++

so when I run this code, the print_conclusion function (I'm assuming) seems to output an unwanted zero.  Can someone please tell me how to not get this zero to show up by suggesting improvements to my code? Thanks

I'm just going to repeat my question so this isn't "mostly code"
so when I run this code, the print_conclusion function (I'm assuming) seems to output an unwanted zero.  Can someone please tell me how to not get this zero to show up by suggesting improvements to my code? Thanks

I'm just going to repeat my question so this isn't "mostly code"
so when I run this code, the print_conclusion function (I'm assuming) seems to output an unwanted zero.  Can someone please tell me how to not get this zero to show up by suggesting improvements to my code? Thanks

I'm just going to repeat my question so this isn't "mostly code"
so when I run this code, the print_conclusion function (I'm assuming) seems to output an unwanted zero.  Can someone please tell me how to not get this zero to show up by suggesting improvements to my code? Thanks

```
[code]
//#include<stdio.h>
#include"stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
//#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

double depth, temperatureCelsius, tempCelToFah;
char usersInput;

string print_introduction() {
    // prints out information to tell the user what this program does.
    //cout << "This program calculates the temperature of the earth when given a depth in kilometers" << endl;
    return "This program calculates the temperature of the earth when given a depth in kilometers\n";
}

double celsius_at_depth(double depth) {
    // computes and returns the celsius temperature at a depth measured in kilometers.
    return temperatureCelsius = 10 * depth + 20;
}

double celsius_to_fahrenheit(double celsius) {
    // converts a Celsius temperature celsius to Fahrenheit.
    return tempCelToFah = 1.8*celsius + 32;
}

double print_conclusion(double depth) {
    //return
    // display the conclusion that what is the temperature in both Celsius and Fahrenheit at depth of the earth
    //does all necessary calculations
    celsius_at_depth(depth);
    celsius_to_fahrenheit(temperatureCelsius);
    cout << "The temperature at depth " << depth << " kilometers.  In Celsius the temperature is " << temperatureCelsius << "\n... in Fahrenheit it is " << tempCelToFah << " degrees.\n";
    return 0;
    //I'm assuming the extra zero in my output comes from this return but I cannot figure out how to get rid of it!!!
}

int main()
{
    //1. print introduction by calling print_introduction() function
    cout << print_introduction() << endl;

    //2. ask user to enter the depth
    cout << "Please enter the depth in kilometers" << endl;

    //3. get user’s input
    cin >> depth;

    //4. print out the conclusion by calling print_conclusion  function
    //cout << print_conclusion(depth); //did not work left zero
    cout << print_conclusion(depth) << endl;

    //5. ask user if he/she wants to continue
    cout << "Would you like to continue? (y/n)?";

    //6. get user’s input
    cin >> usersInput;

    //7. repeat step 2 to step 6 if user picks ‘Y’ or ‘y’
    if (usersInput == 'Y' || usersInput == 'y')
    {
        main();
    }
    else {
        //Stop program
        return 0;
    }
 }
[/code]
```

Comment: Another way to make your question not "mostly code" is to reduce the amount of code in it. Remove lines until you have a minimal example -- it still outputs the unwanted zero, and removing any of the remaining lines causes the unwanted zero to disappear. (Start by commenting out lines starting with `cout <<` until the zero stops appearing.)

Comment: yeah but when you're a new programmer maybe it's something contextual?

Comment: Well, yes, the problem may be something contextual (programming experience is not relevant). All the more reason to simplify that context by removing code that is not needed to reproduce the problem. A minimal example provides the simplest context in which the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cout will print the output of the function. 
Hence, you shouldn't print the output of your function to avoid the 'extra zero'

print_conclusion(depth);